# $|e^{itX}|=1$ when $X\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory

Given a probability space $\Omega,\mathscr{F},p$ and $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ In which p can be seen as a measure on ($\mathbb{R},\mathscr{F}*,P*)$.

Euler identity states $e^{i\pi}=-1$

**(1)How can $|e^{itX}|=1$ when $t$ is real, $i=\sqrt{-1}$?

(2)How can I get $\pi$ out of $tX$?**

Thanks in advance!

According to the suggestion in the comment:
$e^{itX}=\cos (tX) + i \sin(tX)\Leftrightarrow e^{2itX}=\cos^2 (tX) - \sin^2(tX)+2\cos (tX)i \sin(tX)$

If we take the limit: $\lim_{X\to\infty} e^{2itX}=\lim_{X\to\infty}(\cos^2 (tX) - \sin^2(tX)+2\cos (tX)i \sin(tX))=\lim_{X\to\infty}(\cos^2 (tX) - \sin^2(tX))$

As we are interested in the $|e^{itX}|$ we get:$\lim_{X\to\infty} |e^{2itX}|=\lim_{X\to\infty}|(\cos^2 (tX) - \sin^2(tX))|\leqslant\lim_{X\to\infty}|(\cos^2 (tX)| + |\sin^2(tX))|=\lim_{X\to\infty}1=1$

$|e^{2itX}|\leqslant 1\Leftrightarrow|e^{itX}|\leqslant 1$

I do not know if this derivation is right but I still do not get the equality $|e^{itX}|= 1$.

Comment: Use $e^{itX} = \cos (tX) + i \sin(tX)$ and the Pythagorean identity.

Comment: how can I use it?

Comment: I mean the Pythagorean identity

Comment: @UmbertoP. Please check my edit!

Comment: Using Umbertos hint and the definition of the modulus of a complex number

$$\lvert e^{itX} \rvert = \lvert \cos(tX) + i \sin(tX) \rvert = \sqrt{\cos^{2}(tX) + \sin^{2}(tX)} = 1$$

Comment: @Mattos You answered the question! Thanks!